# How to set the form record source to the first record returned in a record set?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to set the first record returned from a record set to the record source of the form "Maintenance" How would I go about doing this?

Why I'm doing is I've constructed a VBA code that finds all the records in a DB based on someones entry into a field - the results may be 0, 1, or greater than 1. How do I change the record set to the first record returned and then, when they press another button, move to the next record returned?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by setting the records set to my SQL statement. Then I set that record set to the Record source of my target Form.

This meant that because the form was constructed in a wizard the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons would function as normal; moving between records.

```
Forms!FrmMaintenance.RecordSource = SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are looking about. But maybe it help you:

```
'access to first field of the first row in record set variable (record set has just beed poppulated)  
rs.Fields(0).Value
'moving to second row of record set         
rs.MoveNext
```

GL!

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain it right - Im getting the results for a record set - how do I set the results to the record set of the form?

Comment: Still I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. But adding new row to the record set is described here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Access/Addnewarowtorecordset.htm .

Answer (score 0):

There is a large communication problem here.

> How do I change the record set to the first record returned

By default a newly opened recorset is at the first record (unless there are none). Show us your existing VBA code that opens a recordset, and why you think it is not already on the first record.

> when they press another button, move to the next record returned?

@Wawrzyniec already posted that.

> how do I set the results to the record set of the form

What results and what form? Do you mean the recordset that you generated internally in VBA?

Comment: yes I do - when i was writing this i wasn't really trying articulating the problem properly. I wanted the user to search for a person and set the results of that search to the Record Source of the form FrmMaintenance. But if two or more records are returned then I should beable to navigate between the returned records.

Comment: I actually managed to solve the problem this morning - so thanks for the interest - on to the next problem!

Comment: Normally i would say post the answer but it